# How to prevent rsyslog from writing hostname?

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have this `rsyslog` setting:

```
if $hostname == "9e4b657a-232c-4bb0-ab9b-7ee6b142c724" then /var/log/heroku.log 
& stop
```

I need to modify this setting in that way so `rsyslog` would stop writing `9e4b657a-232c-4bb0-ab9b-7ee6b142c724` (i.e. hostname) into `/var/log/heroku.log`. The setting should affect this specific file only, i.e. do not affect global settings. How can I achieve that?